# Multi-user,Multi-Touch and simultaneous input

Tags: c#, windows, touch, multi-touch

it seems that it is not possible to control two seprate `window` in Windows 7 simultaneously.
any solution that each process capture it`s own touch input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge this is not currently possible on the Windows operating systems. I haven't heard of it being done in Windows but perhaps you could try to capture touch events and have another process emulate them into each window you want.

I don't know if this sort of hacking is possible in Windows but i've seen it done in Linux systems.